# List field names where value of field is '1' and id=$id

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, list, field-names

I have a table 'jobs' with fields id,p1,p2,p3 where some entries under p1,p2,p3 have a value of '1'. How might I get a simple list of fields (p1,p2, or 3) which have a value of '1' in rows of table jobs where id=$id.

Comment: Let me clarify.  I don't want to actually list the fields in the query because there are a lot of them and they change from time to time. I am at a loss as to where to start.

Comment: that sounds like a poor db design, that's probably where you need to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_result);
$list = '';//or array
foreach ($row as $key=>$val) {
    if ($key != 'id' and $val == 1) { //or if substr($key, 0, 1) == 'p' and $val == 1)
        $list .= $key.', ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Comment: This worked with minor changes. I did it like this:foreach ($key as $key => $val) {
if ($key != 'id' and $val == 1) {  
echo $key; // Field name}}
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT ... WHERE (p1=1 OR p2 =1 OR p3=1)  AND id =$id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE id=$id AND (p1 = 1 OR p2 = 1 OR p3 = 1)
```

Comment: I don't want to actually list the fields in the query because there are a lot of them and they change from time to time.

Comment: So what do you want exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT p1, p2, p3 FROM jobs WHERE id=$id AND (p1 = 1 OR p2 = 1 OR p3 = 1)
```